# Cordova location permission triggers onResume every time

Tags: android, cordova, angular, permissions, angular-google-maps

I have cordova app that has map. When users come to map state, it asks the location permission. A lot of users don't want to give there location so they deny location permission and if the permission window appears 2nd time, it has a checkbox to prevent showing it. So now the problem is that if user press don't show again and deny, the permission always asks in background and deny it also triggering the onPause onResume events. In my onResume event i have a lot of checks that should not be fired every time the permission triggers onResume.

How to stop onResume trigger on permission, or maybe can i have some check when there is a permission trigger then i don't fire onResume?

Answer (score 3):

The Android run-time permissions dialogs are displayed by creating and switching to a new activity. When this happens, the Cordova activity (i.e. your app) is put into the background (triggering the onPause event). When the user makes a choice, the permissions activity is destroyed and your app activity is resumed to the foreground (triggering the onResume event).

So you cannot stop the onResume event from being triggered, because it is being correctly invoked on a change of the foreground activity.

What you can do is to handle the situation more gracefully. One way to do this is to handle the requesting of location permission yourself using the [requestLocationAuthorization()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#requestlocationauthorization) of [cordova-plugin-diagnostic](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin).

For example, by setting a flag before requesting the permission and clearing it momentarily after receiving the permission response, the resume event handler can be made aware of whether it is being resume because of the permissions request:

```
var permissionRequestInProgress = false;

document.addEventListener("resume", function(){
    if(permissionRequestInProgress){
        console.log("Resumed due to permissions request");
    }else{
        console.log("Resumed due to another reason");
    }
}, false);

function requestLocationPermission(){
    permissionRequestInProgress = true;
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
        console.log("Permission is " + status);
        setTimeout(function(){
            permissionRequestInProgress = false;
        }, 100);
    });
}

requestLocationPermission();
```